# Drag & Drop large virtual files using VirtualFileDataObject - After Drop I cannot drag any file until my app gets active again

Tags: c#, wpf, drag-and-drop

I have used successfully the code I found in [Delay's Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/delay/archive/2009/10/26/creating-something-from-nothing-developer-friendly-virtual-file-implementation-for-net.aspx) and everything work as expected, except for a little caveat:

Once the drop is finished unless I click on my WPF application or hover over it, the drop process is not completed and I cannot drag any other file from the file system.

I wrote the following code in the complete action to "trick" the system to activate my app window and it works well when the destination is the file system:

```
 var virtualFileDataObject = new VirtualFileDataObject(
             (vfdo) => 
             {
                 dropPoint = VirtualFileDataObject.NativeMethods.GetMousePosition();
                 //VirtualFileDataObject.NativeMethods.SetMousePosition(dragPoint);
                 //VirtualFileDataObject.NativeMethods.SetMousePosition(dropPoint);
             },
             (vfdo) =>
             {
                 VirtualFileDataObject.NativeMethods.SetMousePosition(dragPoint);
                 //for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) { };
                 //VirtualFileDataObject.NativeMethods.SetMousePosition(dropPoint);
                 VirtualFileDataObject.NativeMethods.SetForegroundWindow(winHandle);
             }
            );
```

The problem is when I drop the files on outlook. The files are dropped without a problem but my "trick" does not work, it's like Outlook decided to hold the process indefinitely until (as I mentioned) I activate my application window.

Has anybody run into a scenario like this one?

Comment: Exactly how you activate this code matters a great deal.  My crystal ball says that you can work around it by using Dispatcher.BeginInvoke().

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for your comment. I tried the approach but then the trick fails for both scenarios. The drop is completed only when I set the focus manually in my app, which is my original problem, which maybe I am solving in the wrong way.

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old thread but in case somebody has the same problem, I fixed the issue moving my methods to a separate class an modifying the logic like this:

```
return new VirtualFileDataObject(
                 (vfdo) =>
                 {
                     ...

                 },
                 (vfdo) =>
                 {
                     myClass.SetMousePosition(startPoint);
                     for (int i = 0; i < 100000000; i++) { };
                     myClass.SetMousePosition(vfdo.DropPoint);
                     ... 
                 }
                );
```